# ModuleNotFoundError while importing from different folder (Python)

Tags: python, import

I am having the age old problem of Module not found while importing files from different folder, kindly help me.
My project directory has the following things:

```
knowledge_generators --> __init__.py
                        knowledge_generator.py
absorb.py
```

In `__init__.py` I have the following content:

```
from knowledge_generator import *
```

And `absorb.py` has:

```
from knowledge_generators import *
```

On running `absorb.py` I get the following error:

```
  File "D:/some/path/project/absorb.py", line 2, in <module>
    from knowledge_generators import *

  File "D:\some\path\project\knowledge_generators\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from knowledge_generator import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'knowledge_generator'
```

Also, on running `__init__.py` everything's working fine(i.e no  ModuleNotFoundError). Kindly help me decipher the problem.

Comment: which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you need to use a [relative import](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references):

In `__init__.py`:

```
from .knowledge_generator import *
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:
Just add your project root directory to environment variable: PYTHONPATH.
so for the below project structure, just add Rootdir path(For e.g: add E:\Projects\Rootdir) in PYTHONPATH.

```
Rootdir
└── pkg2
    ├── b.py
    ├── c.py
     └── pkg2
      ├── b.py
      ├── c.py
```