# Import mysql python function to a different directory (ModuleNotFoundError)

Tags: python, mysql

SOS. I'm in the process of migrating my SQLite database to MySQL and I'd like to share my MySQL connection using a function in `/db/connect.py` with my app at `/app/app.py`. I'm using a temp file to test the connection at `/app/test.py` which contains the function import. The connection from `/db/connect.py` runs successfully by itself. However, even after following other guides to the letter, my function in `/db/connect.py` isn't importing correctly. Even after adding an empty `__init__.py` file in the `/db/` directory.

###### What I've tried

Here's a small sampling of what I've tried [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-import-module-outside-directory/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60659440/use-mysql-flask-connection-in-different-python-file), [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports), and [here](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/python-call-function-from-another-file/) (as well as all other questions in stack overflow on the topic, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59852554/importing-python-function-gives-modulenotfounderror), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70683807/modulenotfounderror-when-importing-from-directory), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809516/modulenotfounderror-while-importing-from-different-folder-python), etc).

###### /db/test.py (temp file with function import)

Imports /db/connect.py > sql_db_connection().

```
from db.connect import sql_db_connection
import db

def get_all():
    conn = sql_db_connection()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from posts")
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    for x in result:
        print(x)
```

###### Error (error from running test.py)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<uname>/<my-long-app-name>/app/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from db.connect import sql_db_connection
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'db'
```

###### /db/connect.py (function for mysql connection)

```
import sshtunnel
import MySQLdb
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Load all env vars
load_dotenv()

def sql_db_connection():
    sshtunnel.SSH_TIMEOUT = 5.0
    sshtunnel.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 5.0

    with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ('ssh.pythonanywhere.com'),
        ssh_username=os.getenv("REMOTE_DB_SSH_USERNAME"), ssh_password=os.getenv("REMOTE_SSH_PASSWORD"),
        remote_bind_address=(
            os.getenv("REMOTE_BIND_ADDRESS"), 3306)
    ) as tunnel:
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(
            user=os.getenv("REMOTE_DB_SSH_USERNAME"),
            passwd=os.getenv("REMOTE_DB_PASSWORD"),
            host='0.0.0.0', port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
            db=os.getenv("REMOTE_DB_NAME"),
        )
        print('Connected!')
        
        return conn

sql_db_connection()
```

###### Tree

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── README.md
├── __pycache__
│   ├── app.cpython-310.pyc
│   ├── app.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── config.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.cpython-38.pyc
│   └── wsgi.cpython-39.pyc
├── app
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── public
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── templates
│   ├── test.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── connect.py
│   ├── database.db
│   ├── dump.sql
│   ├── init_db.py
│   ├── mysql_dump.sql
│   ├── schema.sql
│   └── schema_mysql.sql
├── docker-compose.yml
├── features.md
├── images
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── venv
│   ├── bin
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   ├── man
│   └── pyvenv.cfg
└── wsgi.py
```

Comment: you should go over the second line of the things you have tried, typically the first link in the second row has your answer, and the folder that **contains db** folder should be on your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: you are not mentioning anything about how you ran `test.py` , a small hint, the last word in the command to run it should be `./app/test.py`

Comment: @AhmedAEK Do you mean adding sys.path.append('/db') to test.py? Unfortunately tried that and still get the error.

Comment: **the folder that CONTAINS db** as in the parent of `db` folder namely `/Users/<uname>/<my-long-app-name>`

Comment: Just tried the full path sys.path.append('/Users/<uname>/<my-long-app-name>/db') and ran via python3 app/test.py, but same error.

Comment: `sys.path.append('/Users/<uname>/<my-long-app-name>')` this should be the second line in test.py, the first line should be `import sys`

Comment: @AhmedAEK, that was it! That worked! Thank you so much! Please post as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these two lines as the first two lines in `test.py`

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/<uname>/<my-long-app-name>')
```